# get only 3 words of a String in C#

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to grab the first 3 words of a string (E-mail Subject)in C#,
has anyone done this before?
thanks for your help

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: `text.Split().Take(3)`

Comment: I'm sure lots of people tried it before :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string result = string.Join(" ", str.Split().Take(3));`
(Edited)

Comment: Note `string.Join` can accept an `IEnumerable`, not just an array, as of .NET 4.0.

Comment: You can omit `(' ')` and `ToArray`, at least with .NET 4.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Well, as for the `Split` arguments, it depends on whether you want to split on any whitespace or just spaces.  My guess is that with the input data it might not matter, but it could even be the case that `(' ')` is *wrong*, not just redundant.

Comment: @TimSchmelter There could be a tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> myWordsList = myWords.Split(' ').Take(3).ToList();
```